# Always-On VPN option does not list my PPTP VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I have successfully connected to a PPTP VPN on Android. It is configured simply with an IP address, and no MPPE encrpytion. However, it does not show up under the Always-On option.

I am running Android 4.3 on a Nexus 4.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue too. Apparently Google doesn't deem PPTP secure enough, so they disable it from the "Always On" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Setup DNS options for VPN connection. You may use any public-available DNS servers, for example 8.8.8.8

Note: Android 4.4+ have bug in the Always-On VPN feature: VPN stay connected, but all traffic is blocked because bug in system firewall. For fix this issue search AlwaysOnVpnFix application on Google Play.